# single shot multibox detector: which feature maps do the 4x4 and 8x8 refer to?

Tags: computer-vision, deep-learning

In the article https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.02325, two figures can be found as shown below. One is about the network structure and one is about the feature map.

I would like to know which layers in the network are corresponded to the 4X4 and 8x8 feature maps?

[image: network]

[image: featuremap]

Answer (score 0):

None of the layers in the actual model correspond to the 4x4 and 8x8 feature maps. These feature maps in images (b) and (c) are just examples to illustrate the concept of using different feature layers for prediction.

The feature map sizes for SSD300, for example, are 38x38, 19x19, 10x10, 5x5, 3x3, and 1x1.